# android Spinner followed by ListView - onItemSelected not called

Tags: android, spinner

I have had a good search around and can't seem to find an answer. The method onItemSelected is not being called. Here's the code featured in my activity's onCreate method:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_trips);

    try {
    // if network present.. TODO

    // Load Devices
    deviceList = new ArrayList<Device>();
    DataAsyncTask loadDevices = new DataAsyncTask(0);
    loadDevices.execute(someUrl);
    List<Device> deviceListNames = deviceList;
    final ListView tripListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.trip_list);
    Spinner deviceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.select_device_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<Device> deviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Device>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, deviceListNames);
    deviceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    deviceSpinner.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
    OnItemSelectedListener spinnerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int i, long id) {

            Log.d(TAG, "select is: " + parent.getSelectedItem().toString());   

            DataAsyncTask loadTrips = new DataAsyncTask(1);
            loadTrips.execute(someUrl);
            ArrayAdapter<Trip> tripAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trip>(getApplication(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tripList);
            tripListView.setAdapter(tripAdapter);
            tripListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int i, long id) {

                    Log.d(TAG, parent.getSelectedItem().toString());

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), TripSummary.class);
                    //put value of tripId to intent TODO
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });



         }

         @Override
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
               // TODO
               Log.d(TAG, "nothing selected");
         }

  };
    deviceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

Here's the activity's layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ViewTrips" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/select_device_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/select_device"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/trip_list"
    android:layout_below="@id/select_device_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/trips"
    android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's values are populated and displaying correctly in the Spinner. I am just having an issue with the onItemSelected method in the OnItemSelectedListener() which is set to deviceSpinner - this method is then supposed to populate the ListView, where once clicked takes the user to a new activity. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

I have also tried implementing OnItemSelectedListener for the activity, which doesn't work either.

Note: There's no errors to report in LogCat,

```
Log.d(TAG, "select is: " + parent.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

is not printing.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont u call getSelectedItem method on spinner to get which one is selected, whenever u need data?

Comment: if u are getting any error then plz edit it with question

Comment: My understanding is that parent.getSelectedItem() should be called in onItemSelected of the OnItemSelectedListener() in order to get the item selected - however this is not working for the Log statement (which I am using to test initially).

As stated already, I am not getting any errors.

Comment: you can call spinner.getSelectedItem() from anywhere you want, i use to do it on Save button event or something similar. it will surely return selected item :)

Comment: That is giving me a null pointer now. I haven't seen it used like that before, and from what I have seen it should work in the onItemSelected method

Comment: It can give NPE if your spinner is null. I am using it this way from long. You are doing some mistake then, Try gettin selectedItemPosition, and fetch data from List for corresponding position,

Comment: My spinner is not null, because it is displaying as populated fine. Upon selection, nothing is happening. Surely, onItemSelected should be called when one selects an item? Or am I wrong with that thought?

Comment: Please list simple_list_item_1.xml file

Comment: I am unsure (if by list you meant copy/paste). It is one of the SDK ones I believe.

Comment: `OnItemSelectedListener` is not a top-level class, but an inner-class. What imports does your file have? Also, try using `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` instead.

Comment: I am implementing the spinner and OnItemSelectListener exactly how other examples do, not working